# Facebook Share Dialog Issue iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, hyperlink, sdk

We are using iOS and Android SDKs. On iOS we use Share Dialog and on Android we use Feed Dialog to share the link.

We want to share our website URL through link, URL is very long and formatted which is generated for SEO purpose.

While passing string into content object, it take link string properly, but after sharing it on Facebook. The link is adding "?fb_ref=default" in URL which in-turn not redirecting to our website. The content is showing correctly but the link is not redirecting properly.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post your code on how you're doing the share.

Comment: We are doing the same code suggested on Facebook SDK documentation.

Comment: Might this be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428103/facebook-feed-method-link-by-default-adding-fb-ref-default-at-the-end-how-to-rem

Comment: Above solution doesn't work.

Comment: Although we have got the solution for it by changing link content passing as parameter.